# cannot get exact the same string as reading a txt file in Python

Tags: python, string

the format of my .txt file looks like this:

```
a
abc
apple
hello
```

I am using this code to read them as string:

```
with open("wordsEn.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(i)
```

My output is something like this where there is an additional line after each string. What went wrong there? How can I remove them? also the length of every string is not right.. where the first string 'a' 's legth is 2

```
a

abc

apple

hello
```

Comment: It is the same, but `line` also contains the tailing new line `'\n'` character. By default `print(..)` adds an additional new line. You can use `print(line,end='')` to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` prints what you pass + `\n`. Lines have their own `\n` at the end. Use `strip`:

```
with open('wordsEn.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip())
```

In Python 3 you can use `end` parameter for `print` function:

```
print(line, end='')
```